# Find the menustrip item's submenu which is dynamically created

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, dynamic

Please see this image...

[image]

I've a menu strip with bank item and it has dynamically created sub menus each submenu has Payment & Deposit and each payment and cash has Cheque & Cash.

If I click cash in SBI->Deposit->Cash it should say where is it come from because I've the same form for all of the Banks please tell ne how can I find it

dynamically created menus

```
ToolStripMenuItem bankname = new ToolStripMenuItem(dr["bankabbr"].ToString());
            if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["isdeposit"]) == 1)
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem deposit = new ToolStripMenuItem("Deposit"); 
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["hascashindeposit"]) == 1)
                {
                    ToolStripMenuItem dcash = new ToolStripMenuItem("Cash");
                    dcash.Click += new EventHandler(dcash_Click);
                    deposit.DropDownItems.Add(dcash);
                    dcash.Name = "dcash";
                }
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["haschequeindeposit"]) == 1)
                {
                    ToolStripMenuItem dcheque = new ToolStripMenuItem("Cheque");
                    dcheque.Click += new EventHandler(dcheque_Click);
                    deposit.DropDownItems.Add(dcheque);

                }
                bankname.DropDownItems.Add(deposit);
            }
```

Comment: @Masoud it needed 10reputations to post images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToolStripMenuItem` has a property called `OwnerItem`. You can climb up to a known root item or till you get to the strip and collect your item names in the way.

Im assuming your root is a `ToolStrip`.

```
private void dcash(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    List<string> path = new List<string>();
    path.Add(tsmi.Name);
    while (tsmi.OwnerItem.GetType() != typeof(ToolStrip))
    {
         tsmi = (ToolStripMenuItem)tsmi.OwnerItem;
         path.Add(tsmi.Name);
    }
}
```

Using your example will result in 
`Path[0] = "Cash"`
`Path[1] = "Desposit"`
`Path[2] = "SBI"`

Comment: how can i access the name which is created in form load event?

Comment: I've to use ToolStripMenuItem dcash = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
works... Thanks